# Django - Form from Model is_valid() == False and no errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

My code.

Model:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bid')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bids')
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

View:

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ['value']

    def __init__(self, min_value=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['value'].label = ''
        self.fields['value'].widget.attrs.update({
            'placeholder': 'Bid',
            'class': 'form-group form-control',
            'min': min_value,
        })

def make_bid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bid_form = BidForm(request.POST)
        if bid_form.is_valid():
            # do something
```

HTML:

```
<form class="px-4 py-3" action="{% url 'make_bid' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ bid_form }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Make bid">
</form>
```

**The problem is:** when send post request with data the form will not be valid in `def make_bid`.

`bid_form.errors` is empty.

Data from field available via `request.POST['value']`.

`print(form)` returns

```
<tr><th></th><td><input type="number" name="value" step="0.01" placeholder="Bid" class="form-group form-control" min="&lt;QueryDict: {&#x27;csrfmiddlewaretoken&#x27;: [&#x27;2UB4RwofBmTQagDrp9ImFDJZ4OIIWzhawgp5x7tgje6ySVKzjrmNRQpI5QTUGLMr&#x27;], &#x27;value&#x27;: [&#x27;123123&#x27;]}&gt;" required id="id_value"></td></tr>
```

**The question is:** why form is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the initialization in `def make_bid`.
The Form had `min_value` attribute and initializing in this way: `bid_form = BidForm(request.POST)` means that `request.POST` was associated with `min_value`.

So correct way should look like:

```
def make_bid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bid_form = BidForm(MIN_VALUE, request.POST)
        if bid_form.is_valid():
            # do something
```

where `MIN_VALUE` the same as was used for initializing form during sending to the template.